# Migration from CS-Cart 2.2.x to Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: mysql, category, migration

I try to migrate from CS-Cart 2.2.x Multivendor Edition to Magento 1.9 CE. First I try to move the category data. I try to create dummy category (Fashion) in Magento. I try to look at mysql but I can't find where the data stored. Can Someone tell me which table contained category data?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses the [EAV method](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value) to store data for categories. This means data for the category itself is stored in the tables

```
catalog_category_entity
catalog_category_entity_datetime
catalog_category_entity_decimal
catalog_category_entity_int
catalog_category_entity_text
catalog_category_entity_varchar
```

and with `flat catalog data` turned on indexed into

```
catalog_category_flat_store_[storeid]
```

The category > product relation is stored in the `catalog_category_product...` tables.

Take a look at the [AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) and [Ho_Import](https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import) to transfer your data.